# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 25

Tags: jsp, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I've created ContactUs form through which users can enter the following values:

```
    Email  
    Name  
    Subject  
    Message
```

Using the following code:
        http://www.roseindia.net/mail/sending-an-email-in-jsp.shtml

On clicking the submit button the mail should get send to 1-2 email ids of my company's domain. Users can enter any email-d from any domain and send it to my company's domain email-ids(1-2).

```
    I'm using the following 2 libraries, activation.jar and mail.jar
```

In This case the server connection should be created under port 25?
For this I'm providing the "stacktrace" here. It is showing the following error:

```
    Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 25
```

What is the error, should I write something else in place of live.com?
The name of domain should be written here like emailid=abc@xyz.edu.in, so the host should be smtp.xyz.edu.in?
Please explain me that what is the error?

STACKTRACE:

```
    org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start  
    INFO: The start() method was called on component  
          [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost
    [localhost].StandardContext[/WebApplicationAskAQuestion6]] after start() had  
    already been called. The second call will be ignored.
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.10.10.34, port:    465;
     nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at org.apache.jsp.mail_jsp._jspService(mail_jsp.java:81)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
... 25 more
```

Comment: By doing "telnet smtp.live.com 25", it is showing the following "220 BLU0-SMTP214.phx.gbl Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 re
ady at  Thu, 4 Jul 2013 22:00:13 -0700" What does that mean?

Comment: the code I'm using:  
        http://www.roseindia.net/mail/sending-an-email-in-jsp.shtml

Comment: That message is the standard answerback from Microsoft's mail server. It means that from the computer you're using you have access to smtp.live.com on port 25. If your code is running on a computer somewhere else it might not have that access.

Comment: I'm running on the same computer. Whats changes can I do here, Some said that er have authenticate it by entering usernae/password. So which username/password shoud I enter, or is there any alternative??       Is the code correct? http://www.roseindia.net/mail/sending-an-email-in-jsp.shtml

Comment: Take a look at the site you got the code from. Scroll down to the comments at the bottom. You'll see many, many comments from people suggesting that this code doesn't work for them. I don't know what the problem is - I'm not a JSP or java programmer. I suggest you look for a more reliable piece of code to use.

Comment: Now the email is getting send to gmail, yahoo id's from my gmail id with port 465. But I'nm entering my gmail username and passowrd in the code for authentication. i want to avoid this thing for obvious reasons. Basically I want to create a simple contact us form. The form is with a submit button with Name, E-mail, Subject and Message. Thne mailid here can be any and it gets send to outlook id. So how can I avoid to code it in a way that user don't need to enter his/her password when sending email to my gmail id

Comment: ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 25  

This SMTP connetcion error was resolved by me by adding:  
   
  // used "smtps" and it worked :)
  transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
  
  // port 465 worked for authentication and it solved with gmail, yahoo hosts
  transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465,"myid","password");

So, this is the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 25

This SMTP connection error was resolved by me for gmail and yahoo hosts by adding:

// used "smtps" and it worked :)
  transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");

// port 465 worked for authentication and it solved with gmail, yahoo hosts
  transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465,"myid","password");

So, this is the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can you telnet port 25 at smtp.live.com? [Do you get SMTP greeting message?]

```
telnet smtp.live.com 25
```

**NO** => Your outgoing SMTP connections may be blocked by a firewall.

**Fix**
Send email via [submission port (587)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent) at  smtp.live.com.
It also accepts SMTP connections/submissions but it is less likely to be firewalled out.

```
transport.connect("smtp.live.com",587,null,null);
```

**Explanation**
Outgoing connection to port 25 are frequently blocked as an outgoing spam prevention measure.

Comment: "telnet smtp.live.com 587" and "telnet smtp.live.com 25" is showing ""220 BLU0-SMTP214.phx.gbl Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 re ady at Thu, 4 Jul 2013 22:00:13 -0700

Comment: But when I check for port 25, 587, 465 at "canyouseeme.org", it is showing them as blocked. What to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

[This JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#hotmail) might help.

> Q: How do I access Hotmail (Windows Live mail) with JavaMail?
>
> A: JavaMail is capable of sending and reading messages using Hotmail. All that's required is to properly configure JavaMail. I'll illustrate the proper configuration using the demo programs that come with JavaMail - `msgshow.java` and `smtpsend.java`.
>
> Let's assume your Hotmail username is "user@hotmail.com" and your password is "passwd".
>
> To read mail from your Hotmail Inbox, invoke msgshow as follows:
>
> `java msgshow -D -T pop3s -H pop3.live.com -U user@hotmail.com -P passwd`
>
> By reading the `msgshow.java` source code, you can see how these command line arguments are used in the JavaMail API. You should first try using msgshow as shown above, and once that's working move on to writing and configuring your own program to use Hotmail. The code fragment shown above for connecting to Gmail will also work for connecting to Hotmail by simply changing the host name.
>
> To send a message through Hotmail, invoke smtpsend as follows:
>
> ```
> java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dmail.smtp.port=587
>     smtpsend -d -A -M smtp.live.com
>     -U user@hotmail.com -P passwd someone@example.com
> ```
>
> (Note that I split the command over three lines for display, but you should type it on one line.)
>
> The smtpsend program uses the System properties when creating the JavaMail Session, so the properties set on the command line will be available to the JavaMail Session.
>
> The smtpsend program will prompt for a subject and message body text. End the message body with ^D on UNIX or ^Z on Windows.
>
> Again, you can read the `smtpsend.java` source code to see how the command line arguments are used in the JavaMail API. The code fragment shown above for connecting to Gmail will also work for connecting to Hotmail by simply changing the host name and changing the connect call to `t.connect(host, 587, username, password)`. There is, of course, more than one way to use the JavaMail API to accomplish the same goal. This should help you understand the essential configuration parameters necessary to use Hotmail.

Comment: Now the email is getting send to gmail, yahoo id's from my gmail id with port 465. But I'nm entering my gmail username and passowrd in the code for authentication. i want to avoid this thing for obvious reasons. Basically I want to create a simple contact us form. The form is with a submit button with Name, E-mail,  Subject and Message. Thne mailid here can be any and it gets send to outlook id. So how can I avoid to code it in a way that user don't need to enter his/her password when sending email to my gmail id.

Comment: It's your application that's sending the email.  You need to use an email address associated with your application.  If your company runs its own mail server, or contracts with an ISP for that service, you should use an email id on that server instead of Gmail.

Comment: ok @BillShannon, they told me to just enter "ipaddress" without the authentication....will it work without authenticatin a sthey are using Windows and should I add te librares in WEB-INF folder(uisng netbeans IDE). They've hosted website under APache Tomcat srver

Comment: Should I add the librares in WEB-INF folder(uisng netbeans IDE). Currently I took the libraries from any other location on system and used(compiled) them under NETBEANS IDE. They've hosted website under APache Tomcat and there I think it will show an error that libraries not included.

Comment: By now you've probably had a chance to try it yourself, but yes, you should add the libraries to your WEB-INF/lib.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to add them to your Tomcat lib directory.